# Is there a way to defined common proto structure for response?

Tags: grpc

I have to create a common structure for return response or error form my grpc service. But I want to write reusable `.proto` file.

I write this proto file but dosn't see my requirement.
This is my proto file:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package common;

message Response {

  enum Status {
    OK = 0;
    ERROR = 1;
  }

  Status status = 1;
  string message = 2;

  oneof response {
    DataResponse data = 3;
    ErrorResponse error = 4;
  }
}

// Make DataResponse optional
message DataResponse {
  // Define common fields here
  optional string common_field = 1;
}

message ErrorResponse {
  int32 code = 1;
  string message = 2;
  repeated string field_errors = 3;
}
```

but I get nothing!

Comment: Your questions needs more detail. Your `proto` is well-defined and could provide a way to provide a `Response` messsage to gRPC calls that include either `DataResponse` or `ErrorResponse` message types. What does "but I get nothing" mean? Please include code, commands and errors.

Comment: Your proto does **not** include any Service definitions. Is that part of your problem? See [grpc.io](https://grpc.io) [Introduction](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/)

Comment: it's only message of my proto file not all services